# multiple drop down label searching

Tags: html, search, label, blogger, blogspot

would just like to ask some help regarding my blog I would just like to ask how would I connect the two drop down list boxes of LABELS. To explain it further what I wanted to do is for example i chose a category on first drop down list box of label for example I chose "love" it will show all the posts that has a label of love and when I choose a category from the second drop down list box of LABEL of countries for example Canada it will show all the labels of love with a label of Canada in it. Because what happens is when I choose a label from the second drop down list box it resets from scratch meaning it all shows the posts which has a label of Canada in it without considering the first label that I chose from the first drop down list box.

```
<b:section class='sectopbar' id='sectopbar' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Labels' type='Label'>
 <b:includable id='main'> <b:if cond='data:title'> <h2/> </b:if> <div  class='widget-   content'> <br/> <select  onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> <option>Select a   Category</option> <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'> <option    expr:value='data:label.url'><data:label.name/> (<data:label.count/>) </option>           </b:loop>      </select> <b:include name='quickedit'/> </div> </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
    </b:section>

      <div>
    <b:section class='sectopbar2' id='sectopbar2' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Label2' locked='false' title='Labels' type='Label'>
     <b:includable id='main'> <b:if cond='data:title'> <h2/> </b:if> <div class='widget- content'> <br/> <select onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>  <option>Select a Country</option> <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'> <option expr:value='data:label.url'><data:label.name/> (<data:label.count/>) </option> </b:loop>    </select> <b:include name='quickedit'/> </div> </b:includable>
   </b:widget>
    </b:section>
     <div style='clear: both;'/>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean like this? check the demo first http://pootih.blogspot.com/

see the dropdown options and filter button below the header.